# Need to change object permissions of standard profile-URGENT

Tags: security, profile, sharing, permission-sets

I have Lead OWD set as Private. 
I have 5 users in Marketing User(std obj)..I need to give View All & Modify All permissions on lead object of this profile.

How to approach.?

Cloning marketing User n assigning View All,Modify All is an option,
Assigning Permission sets to users in Marketing user is an option.

I am adviced not to follow above approaches...Any other approach to solve this issue.

Awaiting response ASAP..Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Laxman

Comment: Can you please clarify who has advised you against cloning a standard profile or assigning a permission set to the users ?

Comment: Its a team decision....Cloning profile n giving it a new name would confuse existing users as to which profile should be assigned to newly created users..that is what It should be I guess

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just visibility sharing rules would be another option filtering by that 5 users Role, profile or putting them into a Public group.

Comment: Thanks for reply Torn..I have mentioned the option of extending sharing rules by using Permission set to those 5 users..But I was asked to find some other way of dealing with it..Need solutions rather than above 2 ways mentioned in Question above

Comment: You can also create a trigger onlead that creates a LeadShare for those 5 users.

Comment: The users may increase in future..In that case I need to manually add these new users...I can do this thorugh Lead Sharing rule too,but needs manual work every time new user is created with given profile.

Comment: You just have to add the names of the persons to a Custom Label or Custom Setting query for it on your trigger and the create a sharing for every member on the query WHERE names in : List<string> UserNames.
I don't have much ideas besides this. I exactly don't know why the motivation to say that all previously stated solutions are preferable to not being used  :S.

Comment: Thanks Torn..Im too not sure really as of y those are ignored,,thanks for the suggestions though..  Could you check below link n answer if u have any suggestions... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118999/reduce-the-permissions-of-user