# Reduce the Permissions of User

Tags: security, profile, sharing, standard-objects

I have Lead OWD set to public Read/Write.

I m creating new User with new profile..with Lead permissions as CRED(No view All,Modify All).

I want this user not to see other lead records.

How to achieve?

Comment: Its not possible without changing OWD to private.

Comment: Can u look into given link n check if u can suggest some answer   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118996/need-to-change-object-permissions-of-standard-profile-urgent

Comment: You can't reduce permissions, you can only extend permissions. So as @VigneshwaranG said, you have to start at OWD Private and extend from there